# DSO missing from command line

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to build a node that uses opencv2.4 , when i make it shows me the following error
/home/mahtab/localnix/cv2/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
the .so is present there the given directory . i have both opencv3 and opencv2 in my system. opencv2 is installed locally

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243137/dso-missing-from-command-line/) by [Ma8sa](https://answers.ros.org/users/27905/ma8sa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-09-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akhilesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28821/akhilesh/) on 2016-12-17**:
Hi Ma8sa,

DSO missing is a run time error. So just check your make file where you are linking the library from. And correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fixed this by removing opencv3 from my system and reinstalling ros with opencv2

---

Originally posted by [Ma8sa](https://answers.ros.org/users/27905/ma8sa/) with karma: 26 on 2016-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0